# Order of an object and the name of that object

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's imagine there is an object named "Country", and it is stored in the database table named Countries.

In terms of English grammar, what is the right position of Country/Countries - before the noun or after?

Option 1. For the Country object, there is a Countries table.
Option 2. For the object Country, there is a table Countries.

Which is correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a question about programming, not English.

Comment: Try turning that into a few regular English sentences and see what happens. (1A) For the man Jack, there is a woman Jill. (1B) For the Jack man, there is a Jill woman. (2A) For the singer Madonna, there is a singer Prince. (2B) For the Madonna singer, there is a Prince singer. (3A) For the taxi driver, there is police officer, (3B) For the driver taxi, there is an officer police.

Comment: At the very least, the meaning is changed.

Comment: @Robusto, I've rephrased the question to make it clearer. I need to understand what position of the proper noun is better when the noun needs to be specified as well. For example, 
"I'm watching BBC" is clear for people who know what BBC is. What if I say "I'm watching a BBC channel"? In this case, BBC plays a role of the adjective. It is clear to me that "I'm watching a channel BBC" is not correct. But I can't decide if it is ok to say "a table Country" instead of "a Country table".

Comment: (1) For the object of type Country, there is a table of type Countries. (2) For the Country-type object, there is a Countries-type table.

Comment: @RaufAliev: Use Option 1 (Country object ... Countries table). The inversion that happens in Option 2 is grammatical enough, but the other is simpler and better understood. You would only use Option 2 if you wanted to be more forceful or declamatory or sound more "math-ish".

Comment: "Country object" is a compound noun, and "object Country" has the proper noun in apposition.  Both are grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

> For the country object...

There, **country** is a noun used as an adjective, specifying which object you are referring to.  It is conventional to put the word in italics when it has a specialized significance in your context:

> For the *country* object ...

With your second phrase:

> For the object "country"...

There, "country" is a name, identifying which object you are referring to.

With the second version, you should put the word *country* inside quotation marks; or you can put it in italics—something to indicate that it is a name.

You should be aware that the word **object** there is being used in a specialized manner; it is  jargon that could confuse native speakers who are unfamiliar with things such as entity relationship diagrams.  The word *entity* would be better, IMO, as it is used in many domains.

P.S. Finally, your prepositional phrase construction **for the ... there is** is not as clear as it could be.

> Country entities are stored in the *Countries* table.